# Haskell subclassing and instance overlap

Tags: haskell, inheritance, overlapping, subclassing

Coming from the OOP world, I sometimes find myself trying to use the inheritance pattern in Haskell, with varying degrees of success. Here's a little puzzle I encountered with subclassing (using GHC 8.10.7).

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

import Data.List (sort)

class Collection c a where
    -- gets list of elements in the collection
    elements :: c a -> [a]

class OrderedCollection c a where
    -- gets sorted list of elements in the collection
    orderedElements :: c a -> [a]

instance (Ord a, OrderedCollection c a) => Collection c a where
    -- "default" implementation
    elements = orderedElements

newtype SortedList a = SortedList [a]
    deriving Show

instance (Ord a) => OrderedCollection SortedList a where
    -- need to sort the elements in the list
    orderedElements (SortedList xs) = sort xs

instance Collection SortedList a where
    -- "optimized" implementation: no need to sort
    elements (SortedList xs) = xs

test :: (Ord a, Show a, OrderedCollection c a) => c a -> IO ()
test coll = do
    putStrLn $ "ordered elements: " ++ show (orderedElements coll)
    putStrLn $ "elements:         " ++ show (elements coll)

myList :: SortedList Int
myList = SortedList [3, 2, 1]

main :: IO ()
main = do
    test myList
```

After including the necessary language extensions, this still gave me an error: `Overlapping instances for Collection c a arising from a use of ‘elements’`. It suggests using `IncoherentInstances`. Since this extension is now deprecated in favor of per-instance pragmas, I added an `INCOHERENT` pragma to the subclass instance:

```
instance {-# INCOHERENT #-} (Ord a, OrderedCollection c a) => Collection c a where
...
```

This successfully compiled. However, the result was not what I expected, as the output was:

```
ordered elements: [1,2,3]
elements:         [1,2,3]
```

What I wanted was for the specialized implementation of `Collection` for `SortedList` to override the default (in an OO language, `SortedList` would inherit from `OrderedCollection` and then override the `elements` method). But here the type checker does not know to use `SortedList`'s custom `Collection` implementation, because the type signature of `test` only imposes the constraint `OrderedCollection c a`.

Next, I tried adding the `Collection` constraint:

```
test :: (Ord a, Show a, Collection c a, OrderedCollection c a) => c a -> IO ()
```

This gave me the output I wanted:

```
ordered elements: [1,2,3]
elements:         [3,2,1]
```

However, GHC also issued a warning about "fragile inner bindings" and suggested I add the `MonoLocalBinds` extension, which silences that warning. In any case, I'm not thrilled with having to include the `Collection c a` constraint (given it's implied by `OrderedCollection c a`), or having to use incoherent instances.

Interestingly, if I changed the `INCOHERENT` pragma to `OVERLAPPABLE`, it still compiled, and it also allowed me to remove `MonoLocalBinds`.

My question is, are there any alternative approaches to achieving the desired "inheritance" behavior here, without needing the redundant constraint in `test`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write this:

```hs
instance ... => Collection c a where
```

You're declaring a `Collection` instance for *all types ever*. And it doesn't matter at all what's on the left of the fat arrow `=>`. Constraints do not participate in instance resolution. When the compiler tries to lookup an instance for a particular type, it only looks at what's on the right of the fat arrow `=>`, and only after finding a matching instance does it check if its constraints are satisfied. And if they're not, the compiler won't go back to look for another instance. That's how instance resolution works, and there are good reasons for it.

So, to reiterate: `Collection c a` means that this is an instance for *all types*.

And therefore, any subsequent `Collection` instances you might declare would of course be overlapping.

---

Thankfully, in this *particular* case, there is a better way: you can declare default methods without creating a universal instance like that. To do that, declare the method right inside the class declaration. And yes, you can put constraints on it too (see [docs](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/9.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/exts/default_signatures.html)):

```hs
class Collection c a where
    -- gets list of elements in the collection
    elements :: c a -> [a]
    default elements :: OrderedCollection c a => c a -> [a]
    elements = orderedElements
```

---

But more generally, while type classes plus existential quantification is technically equivalent to OOP-style class hierarchies, if you try to actually model your domain like that, it would be more and more awkward and painful the further you go. It's a bit like trying to model ADTs in something like Java. Technically possible, but oh so messy!

There are some legitimate cases where a class hierarchy may make sense (one notable example is the GHC exception system), but *most of the time* there are much simpler ways.